"undefined: utils.GetTrimmedParam" Error when running the 'Hello World' code from 'Getting Started'
I ran the 'Hello World' code mentioned in the official GoFiber document document but got the following error:
$ go run main.go
# github.com/gofiber/fiber
/home/user/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gofiber/fiber@v1.14.6/path.go:175:21: undefined: utils.GetTrimmedParam

The code that I ran was:
package main

import "github.com/gofiber/fiber"

func main() {
  app := fiber.New()

  app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) {
    c.Send("Hello, World!")
  })

  app.Listen(3000)
}

What I did before running this code was as follows:
go mod init main

$ go get -u github.com/gofiber/fiber

$ go get -u github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2
go: added github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2 v2.52.5
go: added github.com/mattn/go-runewidth v0.0.15
go: added github.com/rivo/uniseg v0.4.7

$ go get -u github.com/gofiber/fiber/v3
go: added github.com/gofiber/fiber/v3 v3.0.0-beta.3
go: added github.com/gofiber/utils/v2 v2.0.0-beta.5

go mod tidy

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

V1 is no longer majntained so try v2 - import "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2".

The problem was with this:
$ go get -u github.com/gofiber/fiber
$ go get -u github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2
$ go get -u github.com/gofiber/fiber/v3

I shouldn't have had to add different versions of gofiber as dependencies, especially the v1 which is now no longer supported.
Problem was solved after I deleted the go.mod file and tried again with only v2 of GoFiber.

The main issue was that you were importing github.com/gofiber/fiber which is an old version (you could get this to work by running go get github.com/gofiber/utils@v0.0.10 to downgrade the utils package, looks like there was a breaking change). Just using import github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2 should have done the trick.  Note that running go mod tidy will remove unused packages from your go.mod automatically and you don't need to run go get ... often, because go mod tidy will download any neccessary packages.

I try to do this example. Its success. I guess your init mod method wrong?Dont need to get, just go mod tidy.


